# Three ways to harmonize a note with a triad?

Tags: theory, piano, chords, harmony

For simplicity assume we're in C major. Let's say I'm playing a song, and I want to play a basic triad chord to harmonize whatever current melody note is played. In this example say the melody is a D note that I would play with my right hand. Then for my left hand, I think there's three possible chord combinations that I can play (I usually pick the one that sounds best):

1. The note is on the left of the triad
2. The note is in the middle of the triad
3. The note is on the right of triad.

Does this sound about right?

Edit: In this question I (incorrectly?) assumed the triad has to include the melody note. I haven't ever seen it not including the melody note, but maybe that's just due to my inexperience.

[image]

Comment: You mean with no accidentals or alterations, right?

Comment: yep no accidentals completely diatonic

Comment: This is a related video that I found to be quite interesting: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JXfQsHT5c30&t=528s

Comment: Have you considered inverting your triads?

Comment: inversions don't count (for this question)

Comment: Using only the parameters given in your question, Laurence's answer is accurate. While Todd's has many more votes, I don't think he's answered the question you pose. Any chance of some clarity, as right now, it's a vaguely written question. Unless it's exactly what you want to ask - triads only, only containing C key diatonic notes, and all containing a D note. In which case, it's a simple 'yes', there are only those three.

Comment: @Tim I edited the question at the bottom. feel free to edit it the title or answer any way you want though if you think it's not clear.

Comment: It's better now. Before, it gave the impression that the triad had to include note D. Hence Todd's answer, which suggests other notes. But strictly speaking a triad will contain a root, third and fifth. Hence, for example, D, G and A, (sus4) isn't a triad, it just has three notes.

Comment: @Tim I think part of the confusion might be whether or not the question separates the triad from the melody or not. In other words, is the question about a melody note and also a separate triad for a total of four notes at once, or is the question merely about a single triad and only three notes? It seems that foreyez has confirmed that the former interpretation is what was intended.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - yes, you're right. Something that never needed to happen had the question been posed more clearly. It was ambiguous, but my answer wasn't appropriate anyway. Sometimes one has to read between the lines, and you did.

Comment: @Tim In defense of foreyez, it took me forever to understand what you found unclear about the question. It seemed completely clear to me when I read it, but I was pre-disposed to that interpretation because I've been collaborating with a melody writer who is also very picky about the chords I try to put under the melodies, so I've been living in "how to harmonize a melody" land for about 18 months now. When I sell my collaborator on a chord that doesn't have the melody note as a chord tone, it's a small victory for me.

Comment: You just asked *another* question! Yes, probably more than 99%. 'Laura' is one that springs to mind with melody notes outside the written chords - although instead of them being m7, they *could* have been m9.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If by “C major,” you are assuming the key of C, with, as you explained in a comment, no alterations and no accidentals, and using the note “D” as a reference point, and if you are assuming a triad to mean only the adjacent diatonic intervals of 3rds (based on your graphic), then yes, what you have built is accurate. It is pretty fundamental to music theory.

Of course, this applies to any note in the scale, not just D. In C major, start on C, and you can have C be the root (C major), the third (A minor), or the fifth (F major); go to D, and the same applies; go to E, and the same applies; etc.

Your question more particularly seems to assume the constraint that the melody be part of the triad itself or be a note that is in common with a note in the triad. This need not be the case; indeed, it often is not the case. Melodies can be tricky, fluid things when you are considering harmonization.

Take the well-known “Auld Lang Syne,” for instance:

[image: “Auld Lang Syne” harmony]

[LilyBin link, with MIDI audio](http://lilybin.com/b2jvh7/1)

In this very basic harmonization, even in the *first measure*, we encounter a melody note that does not “fit” into the triad of F major. In almost *every* measure, there is a melody note that does not “fit” into the triad that is harmonized with it.

On the other hand, if you harmonized *every* note in its own triad according to the rules in your question, it might arguably sound *worse*:

[image: “Auld Lang Syne” too much harmony]

[LilyBin link, with MIDI audio](http://lilybin.com/a7w9qz/1)

The combination of melody notes that *are* part of the triad and that *are not* part of the triad is often what provides *musical interest*.

This is to say nothing, of course, of *extending* the harmony beyond triads—suspensions, extensions, and borrowed, oh my! But, given the constraints you provided in your question, yes, notes can be harmonized with any of the three notes in a diatonic triad of which that note is a part—but when harmonizing a melody, I think it is often advisable to know how *best* to produce *good music*. To *only* look for triads that “fit” the melody in the way you describe seems like an inadvisable course to stay on, but it is a good *starting* point.

Comment: Note that the asker has stated elsewhere that he refuses to learn to read music (don't ask). Of course, the score in this answer will be helpful for others who are curious about the same thing.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Anyway, many of others probably can't hear the second version in their heads, and don't have access to an instrument right now, so a link to a recording or a MIDI would help both OP and other readers.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I said I refuse to learn a song by reading sheet music. it's different when we're talking theory and analyzing then I'm for it. and I think this answer is great. I wish lilybin would use html audio to play the thing instead of me having to download it. also I can't play the midi file with quicktime for some reason so I'm having to drag the midi files to garageband. I'm on a mac.

Comment: @foreyez Sorry, I must have misunderstood when you wrote: "*I'm illiterate in music by design. I don't read or write music and will never do so as I prefer everything by ear.*"

Comment: @ToddWilcox sigh. you know what I mean. funny I actually found a video the other day of another guy that feels the same way. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9HoIJK6XW80

Comment: @foreyez All evidence suggests that I didn't actually know what you meant.

Comment: Do I need to separate you two?

Answer (score 13):

There are actually more ways, many more ways.

One fairly straightforward way is to make the melody note the seventh of the chord. So in this case the chord would be E G B.

From there you could make the melody note an add 9 by using the chord C E G, but an octave lower, add 11 with A C E, etc.

Depending on how long you are playing the D and on what beat and whether it is emphasized or not, you could "harmonize" it with almost any chord. Each choice has a different flavor.

You could also borrow triads that contain D from related keys. And of course you could branch out beyond triads.

Comment: The OP asks about notes *with* a triad, then gives examples of *those* triads. Should the question read *within* rather than *with*, as your answer alludes to the latter, while mine leans to the former? Unclear question, or unclear translation thereof?

Comment: @Tim I read it as asking how many ways are there to harmonize a melody note using a triad. He proposed three possible triads, a D minor triad, a B diminished triad, and a G major triad, and then asks if there are any others. I suggest that there are many other triads that can harmonize with that note, depending on the desired overall sound.

Comment: The OP harmonised D with *two other notes*, thus making his triad. There wasn't really mention of any more than *two other notes*, otherwise, it's not a triad. You're right, in that D could be mixed with a myriad of other notes, diatonic or not, but I wonder whether the triad part (including D) is the crux. Not happy with the wording of the question. Seems to allow too much interpretation.

Comment: @Tim The diagram doesn't exactly show what the text relates. Note the discussion of right hand playing a D and the left hand playing a triad. I think the diagram is just there to show that he assumes that the melody must always be a chord tone, not that he would only be playing three total notes in his hypothetical situation. Rather, he would be playing one note with his right hand and a triad with his left for a total of four notes.

Comment: I'm still concerned with the vagueness of the question. A triad is a note, its 3rd and its 5th. Three notes. And apparently diatonic, which seemingly brings it all down to the three shown. So that D can be root, 3rd or 5th of a triad, but the other two notes must belong to key C. So the correct answer is 'yes'. What am I missing?

Comment: @Tim You're looking at the question title. Todd is answering the question in the text,  "I want to play a basic triad chord to harmonize whatever current melody note is played." The answer being, "Don't limit yourself to the melody always being a chord tone."

Comment: @Tim Todd's answer is valid. the question was just about how to harmonize using any triad within the diatonic scale. my experience was just that I see 99% of the time the melody note tends to be one of the chord tones. (note that the 99% could be due to my lack of experience, if its not that high let me know!)

Answer (score 6):

It's a very narrow question.  But, within its terms, yes you're correct.

But that information isn't terribly useful.  Because there are triads other than diatonic ones.  And there are chords other than triads.  And there are 'non-chord tones'.  And all these are VERY commonly used, even in quite simple music.

But if you INSIST on "I want to play a basic triad chord" I can't argue with your logic.

Answer (score 1):

That is right if you want an easy guaranteed harmony for a single note. When you consider music is a series of notes you also need to consider the sequence of chords you have and their relation to one another. It works playing several notes with the same chord, some that are in the chord and some that are not. Music that only uses "safe" harmonies tends to sound static and boring. Try holding down a chord and seeing how each note of the scale (or out of it)sounds against that chord. Some cry out to you to move them back or forward to a more harmonic note. If the next note of a melody does this it gives a feeling of tension then resolution giving a sense of dynamics in the tune. You can do this all by ear but it helps to know what the intervals between notes are so you can put a name on what you like to help remember it and duplicate it in another key.